# How do you apply a function to all the elements in the array?

Tags: c

I want to write a program with following signature where the function will be applied to all the elements of the array in c.

```
void map(unsigned(*function_name)(unsigned), 
         size_t funct_length, 
         arr_name[funct_length]);
```

Everything is unsigned.

Comment: `funct_length` seems an odd name for a parameter whose purpose appears to be to convey the *array*'s length.

Comment: That does not look like valid C function signature.

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with iterating over all the array elements, and calling the function once for each one?

Comment: `arr_name[funct_length]` seems not right

Comment: It's almost a valid function signature, but there needs to be an element type for parameter `arr_name`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger                                                                                                        
     for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
        arr[i]=fn(arr[i]);         
         }.      something like this?

Comment: If you are new to C it seems odd that you start with things like function pointers, there is lots of things you could learn before you get to that.

Comment: Yes, @Lena, something along those lines.

Comment: @anastaciu, as I read the function signature, the concept is to *apply* a mapping, represented by the passed function, to the elements of the specified array.  Not to *create* a map.  But who's to day?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few blanks on your question, but the following code provides you with a starting point. Some issues:

`(*function_name)(unsigned)` is a pointer function, the other parameters are the array size and a pointer to the array, I produced two invented functions, `map_add_point` and `map_remove_point`, so each function will be applied to all the elements of the array.

```c
void map(unsigned (*function_name)(unsigned), size_t funct_length, unsigned arr_name[]);

unsigned map_add_point(unsigned);
unsigned map_remove_point(unsigned);

int main()
{
    unsigned points_a[] = {1,2,3};
    unsigned points_b[] = {1,2};

    map(map_add_point, sizeof(points_a)/sizeof(unsigned), points_a);
    map(map_remove_point, sizeof(points_a)/sizeof(unsigned), points_b);

    return 0;
}

void map(unsigned (*funct_length)(unsigned), size_t length, unsigned arr_name[])
{
    size_t n;

    for (n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        (*funct_length) (arr_name[n]);
    }

}


unsigned map_add_point(unsigned point)
{
        printf("\nPoint to add: %d", point);
        return 0;
}


unsigned map_remove_point(unsigned point)
{
        printf("\nPoint to remove: %d", point);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic:

```
void map(unsigned(*function_name)(unsigned), size_t funct_length, unsigned arr_name[funct_length])
{
    while(funct_length--)
    {
        *arr_name = function_name(*arr_name);
        arr_name++;
    }
}
```